Ошибка при решении задачи на Python
Недавно начал знакомство с ООП, решал задачу со следующим условием:

Создайте класс Book с атрибутами author, title и release. 
Присвойте этим атрибутам значения "Айзек Азимов", "Я, робот", 1950.

Написал, как мне казалось сносный код:
class Book:
    def __init__(self):
        self.author = "Айзек Азимов"
        self.title = "Я, робот"
        self.release = 1950

Но выдает ошибку следующего содержания:

Ошибка запуска Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "tester.python3", 
line 15, in  print(Book.author) 
AttributeError: type object 'Book' has no attribute 'author'

Буду признателен за помощь в решении!

Так про инит в задаче ничего не сказано... попробуйте просто создать класс с атрибутами.

Возможно атрибуты должны быть именно у класса, тогда код будет таким:
class Book:
    author = "Айзек Азимов"
    title = "Я, робот"
    release = 1950


Как вариант, создайте экземпляр класса и далее работайте с экземпляром.
class Book():
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.author = "Айзек Азимов"
        self.title = "Я, робот"
        self.release = 1950

book = Book()                                     # +++
print(book.author) 


Сильно подозреваю, что строку print(Book.author) автор вопроса менять не может
